# Automated Builds in single server Azure devops server

Tags: tfs, build, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2020, automated-builds

If i'm deploy azure devops server on single machine, why extensive use of automated build, test, or release likely will cause performance issues ?

thanks!

Comment: What specs does the server have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single-server deployment consists of a single machine and it likely will cause performance issues because of the following reason:

- Limited size of RAM. For evaluation or personal use - 2 GB, scale up to 250 users - 4 GB and scale up to 500 users - 8 GB.

You can refer to [Requirements for Azure DevOps on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020#single-server-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it really depends on the server and its specs. If it had RAID SSDs, 64GB memory and an AMD 32 core Ryzen Threadripper, I'd not be worried too much :o).

But it you're running multiple parallel build jobs on a server it will have to handle massive I/O on the drives and CPU may spike, many compilers know very well how to make use of all the CPU cores you hand to them.